# Blazor: Render dynamic elements from a list of components. Nothing is shown

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

In my dom I am doing this:

```
        @foreach (var documentUploader in documentUploaderElements)
        {
            <documentUploader />
        }
```

I init the page like this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var doc = new QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.DocumentUploader();
    documentUploaderElements.Add(doc);
    StateHasChanged();

    base.OnInitialized();
}
```

While the list is just that:

```
private List<QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.DocumentUploader> documentUploaderElements = new List<Shared.Details.DocumentUploader>();
```

Now, from my understanding this should render at least one element in the dom. But nothing is shown and no error thrown.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the whole documentUploader Comp:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager



<div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 80%" >

    <strong style="margin-top: 20px">Dokumenten-Titel*</strong>
    <p>Zur Anzeige auf der Artikelseite</p>
      <input @bind="Title" style="margin-top: 10px;" type="text" maxlength="80" placeholder="Titel: z.B: Original Rechung 01.01.2020">
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
          <strong class="headlines_options">Art des Dokuments</strong>
          <select id="selectedOption" style="margin-top: 10px; color: black; font-size: 13px; max-width: 80%"  class="form-control" @bind="TypeOfResell">
            <option selected style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Rechnung"><strong>Rechnung</strong></option>
            <option style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Garantie"><strong>Garantie</strong></option>
            <option style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Andere"><strong>Andere</strong></option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <InputFile OnChange="@SingleUpload" class="custom-input-file" />
</div>


 


@code {
    private string Title = "";
    private string TypeOfResell = DocumentTypes.Rechnung.ToString();

    private async Task SingleUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        //do something with bytes
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    enum DocumentTypes
    {
        Rechnung,
        Garantie,
        Andere
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to understand what this means.  You're using very unfriendly names for things, not showing which components the code snippets are in, and provide no idea what's in your data objects.  Read about [mre] on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we are walking on a wrong direction. Here's my code:

```
@foreach (DocumentUploader item in _duList)
{
    <DocumentUploader />
    <item />
}

@code {
    private IList<DocumentUploader> _duList = new List<DocumentUploader>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var doc = new DocumentUploader { content = "sadf" };
        _duList.Add(doc);
    }
}
```

And I have `DocumentUploader.razor` like this.

```
<h3>DocumentUploader</h3>

<div>@content</div>

@code {
    public string content { get; set; } = "default content";
}
```

As we can see, although the `item` here is the type of `DocumentUploader` component, but it doesn't mean we could use `item` as the component tag.

[image]

Then the test result is like what OP mentioned, no dom rendered if I don't have `<DocumentUploader />` in the `foreach`.

To load component in the for loop, we could change code to this.

```
<h3>DocumentUploader</h3>

<div>@content</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]//add parameter attribute
    public string content { get; set; } = "default content";
}
```

Then in the parent component,

```
@foreach (var item in _duList)
{
    <DocumentUploader content="@item" />
}

@code {
    private IList<string> _duList = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _duList.Add("content1");
        _duList.Add("content2");
        _duList.Add("content3");
    }
}
```

[image]

============================

Hi, here's my test result with your component code.
[image]

Comment: yes, this is exactly what my issue is, however; i dont just wanan rendere a single string. I edited my answer with myf full document uploader component. could you have a look again?

Comment: @innom Hi, I couldn't get your point about your requirement... I test with your component and it could be loaded. And since it seems that the component doesn't require parameters from the parent componenet. I guess it might be a new question and you could create a new ticket with detailed requirement/issue.

Comment: @Tiny Wang I think the OP is trying to use RenderFragment for child content, but doesn't know what it is called.